# include_package_data=True does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I use `include_package_data=True` with `setuptools`.

Despite I have `include_package_data=True` when I run `python setup.py install` my `*.xml` and `*.ttl` (and other) files are not installed.

What is my error? Or is it a bug of `setuptools`? What to do?

From https://github.com/vporton/xml-boiler `setup.py`:

```
from coverage.annotate import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py as DistutilsBuild


class MyBuild(DistutilsBuild):
    def run(self):
        DistutilsBuild.run(self)
        os.system('make')


setup(
    name='xml-boiler',
    version='0.0.2',
    url='https://github.com/vporton/xml-boiler',
    license='AGPLv3',
    author='Victor Porton',
    author_email='porton@narod.ru',
    description='Automatically transform between XML namespaces',

    use_scm_version=True,
    setup_requires=['setuptools_scm'],
    packages=find_packages(),
    # package_data={'': ['**/*.xml', '**/*.ttl', '**/*.net', 'data/assets/*', 'data/scripts/*.xslt',
    #                    'xmlboiler/doc/*.html', 'xmlboiler/doc/*.css']},
    include_package_data=True,
    scripts=['bin/boiler'],
    # Does not work for non-root install:
    # data_files = [
    #     ('/etc/xmlboiler', ['etc/config-cli.ttl'])
    # ],
    test_suite="xmlboiler.tests",

    cmdclass={'build_py': MyBuild},
)
```

Here is my `MANIFEST.in`:

```
recursive-include xmlboiler *.xml *.ttl *.xslt
recursive-include xmlboiler/core/data/assets *
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Needs `zip_safe=False` flag to prevent installation inside a ZIP file.

Comment: It did not solve for me. I dont know why is this a accepted answer

Comment: @Tessaracter But it worked for the original asker, that is me. So I accepted my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue using this `MANIFEST.in`:

```
include setup.json
recursive-include . *.coffee
```

- the `.coffee` files were present in the .tar.gz file but not installed
- the problem was *not* resolved by adding `zip_safe=False`
- it **was** resolved by switching from `recursive-include` to individual `include`s

This is using

- wheel 0.32.3
- twine 1.12.1
- setuptools 39.2.0